# By simplifying right and left hand sides of equation separately.. Trig identity Verification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\frac{\csc\theta - 1}{\cot\theta} = \frac{\cot\theta}{\csc\theta+1}$

I can't figure out how to verify this using only one side. I verified by simplifying both sides and the identity is true. But our teacher requires us to verify it using only one side.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "using one side"

Comment: If you don't want to upvote or select any existing answers, maybe we need more information about what you want. You could edit in how you've already proved the result, then identify which part of your solution isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*} \frac{\csc\theta-1}{\cot\theta} &= \frac{\frac1{\sin\theta}-1}{\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}} = \frac{1-\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} \\
&= \frac{(1-\sin\theta)(1+\sin\theta)}{\cos\theta(1+\sin\theta)} = 
\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\cos\theta(1+\sin\theta)}\\ &=\frac{\cos\theta}{1+\sin\theta} = \frac{\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}}{\frac{1+\sin\theta}{\sin\theta}} = \frac{\cot\theta}{\csc\theta+1}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Note,

$$\frac{\csc\theta-1}{\cot\theta}
= \frac{\csc^2\theta-1}{\cot\theta(\csc\theta+1)}
= \frac{\cot^2\theta}{\cot\theta(\csc\theta+1)}
= \frac{\cot\theta}{\csc\theta+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just do it one scratch paper on both sides, then put it in a final draft in one direction, hand it in to your teacher and lie to him and say you did it on one side:

$\color{blue}{\text{Do steps 1 to 5 first}}$

1)$\frac {\csc \theta -1}{\cot \theta}=$

2)$\frac {\frac 1{\sin \theta} -1}{\frac {\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}}=$

3)$(\frac 1{\sin \theta} -1)\frac {\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}=$

4)$\frac 1{\cos \theta} - \frac {\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$

5) $\frac {1-\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}=$

Now do the other side but present your work backwards

......

Now you know that $\frac MN = \frac ab \iff Mb = Na$ so if you want to do that on "one side" you'd take the $\frac MN = \frac {Mb}{Nb}$ and see what happens.

So take the denominator you got from Step 9 and see what happens when you multiply top and bottom by it

.....

$\color{green}{\text{Do steps 10 to 13 last; try to tie step 5 to step 9}}$

10) $\frac {1-\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}\times \frac {1+\sin \theta}{1+\sin \theta}=$

11) $\frac {1-\sin^2 \theta}{\cos\theta(1 + \sin\theta)}=$

12) $\frac {\cos^2 \theta}{\cos\theta (1 + \sin\theta)}=$

13) $\frac {\cos \theta}{1 + \sin\theta}$

=========

$\color{red}{\text{Do steps 6 through 9 second but present them in reverse order}}$

9)$=\frac {\cos \theta}{1+\sin \theta}$

8)$= \frac {\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}\sin\theta}{(\frac 1{\sin\theta} + 1)\sin \theta}$

7)$=\frac {\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}}{\frac 1{\sin\theta} + 1}$

6)$=\frac {\cot \theta}{\csc \theta +1}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\csc(\theta)-1}{\cot(\theta)} = \frac{ \cot(\theta)(\csc(\theta)-1)}{\cot^2(\theta)}= \cdots.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Multiply the numerator and denominator of the LHS by $\csc\theta + 1$, then use the identity $1 + \cot^2\theta = \csc^2\theta$ to simplify the resulting expression.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply by one and use the associative property of multiplication.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\csc\theta - 1}{\cot\theta}&= \frac{\csc\theta - 1}{\cot\theta}\bigg(\frac{\csc\theta + 1}{\cot\theta}\cdot\frac{\cot\theta}{\csc\theta + 1}\bigg)\\
&= \bigg(\frac{\csc\theta - 1}{\cot\theta}\cdot\frac{\csc\theta + 1}{\cot\theta}\bigg)\frac{\cot\theta}{\csc\theta + 1}\\
&= \dots\\
\end{align}$$